# setTimeout() cannot call nested functions properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, settimeout

I have a timeout function that looks like this:

```
setTimeout(this.logout, 1000);
```

login method:

```
logout() {
    this.auth_token = "";
    this.loggedIn = false;
    this.emitLogedInStatusChange();
}

isLoggedIn() {
    return this.loggedIn;
}

private emitLogedInStatusChange() {
    this.LoggedInStatusChangedEmitter.emit({
        value: this.loggedIn
    });
}
```

where event emitter tells main component where the value for loggedIn is changed.
The problem is `this.emitLogedInStatusChange();` where I got an error message:

> this.emitLogedInStatusChange is not a function

My Question is how to properly call this function inside logout so setTimeout could work?

Here is where I call it:

```
map((res) => { 
 if (res.username === username) { 
   this.auth_token = res.access_token; 
   this.sessionId = res.SessionID;  
   this.loggedIn = true; 
   this.expires = res.expires_in; 
   setTimeout(this.logout, this.expires*1000); 
   this.emitLogedInStatusChange(); 
  }
```

Comment: where your timeout is called ?

Answer (score 9):

When passing functions and methods it's always necessary to take care how that affects the scope of `this`. By default JS uses the scope of the caller.

There are ways to explicitly specify the scope to be used:

```
setTimeout(this.logout.bind(this), 1000);
```

but I can't be sure because your code doesn't show where the code is called from.

Alternatively

```
setTimeout(() => this.logout(), 1000);
```

can be used but that seems less succinct. For other use cases where parameters are passed to the callback, they need repeated like

```
someFunction((a, b, c) => this.logout(a, b, c), 1000);
```

Comment: it is post method in angular 2 for login

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there. Code in comments is unreadable. What I want to know is where the calling code is in relation to the called code (same class, other class, how did the other class get the reference to the function)

Comment: setTimeout(() => this.logout(), 1000); that was what I needed! thanksss

Answer (score 2):

`setTimeout` will add function call to event loop and will fire it from there.
 So `this` is lost and set to `window`(default). You will have to bind `this` to your function.

```
setTimeout(this.logout.bind(this), 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two alternatives to solve your problem, the first one (as the other replies suggest) is to bind your method call to `this` in order to keep context.

```
setTimeout(this.logout.bind(this), 1000);
```

The second solution is to declare logout as a variable, this way you don't loose context upon calling it:

```
logout = () => {
    this.auth_token = ""; 
    this.loggedIn = false;
    this.emitLogedInStatusChange();
}
```

and then you call it this way:

```
setTimeout(this.logout, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the function to the setTimeout().

I would recommend using an anonymous function, which calls the desired function instead:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    this.logout();
}, 1000);
```